# I have to find the gcd of 3 unsigned 16 bit numbers. It runs but does not give the proper output. What can be wrong in my code?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

This is an assembly language 8086 program to find the gcd of three unsigned 16 bit numbers.

I have checked the code several times and I feel this should be correct.

It runs and gives neither error nor warning but it gives output as different symbols (like smileys, arrows and all).

I can't figure out what to do next.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
        arr DW 4800h,1600h,3200h
        gcd DW ?

.code
        main proc
                mov ax,@data
                mov ds,ax

                mov cx,0
                mov si,offset arr
                mov bx,[si]
                jmp L1

        L1:

                inc si
                inc cx
                mov ax,[si]

                jmp compare

       compare:

                cmp ax,bx
                jg up1
                jb excg
        up1:


                aad
                div bx
                cmp dx,0000h
                je exit
                jmp up2


       excg:
               xchg ax,bx
               jmp up1
       up2:

                mov ax,bx
                mov bx,dx
                mov dx,0
                jmp up1
       exit:
                mov gcd,bx
                cmp cx,2
                jne L1
        je display

      display:         


                mov dx,bx
                mov ah,2
                int 21h

                mov ax,4c00h
                int 21h

                main endp

     end main
```

Comment: Normally getting symbols and stuff means your integer->ASCII conversion is wrong, e.g. printing a single `x + '0'` byte when `x` is outside the 0-9 range, and thus needs multiple characters to represent in ASCII decimal.  Use a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: It looks like your code can reach `div bx` without setting DX. So the upper half of your dividend is whatever garbage was left there.  Also, `jg up1` (signed greater-than) / `jb excg` (unsigned below) definitely requires a comment!!  Why do you want to jump to `excg` only if `ax <unsiged bx && !(ax >signed bx)`?  Also, how does [`AAD`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aad) make any sense?  Your inputs are binary integers, not 2-byte unpacked BCD, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Before `mov ax,[si]` you got but a single `inc si`. Since you're dealing with words this needs to be `add si, 2`.

Comment: *I have checked the code several times and I feel this should be correct.* You should try to confirm your feelings by checking your calculations step by step in a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a assembly language 8086 program to find the gcd of three unsigned 16 bits number.

You're trying to implement [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) but your code turned out to be messy and faulty.

. The pointer `SI` must increment by 2 since you're working with words.
. The `aad` instruction should really be a `cwd` instruction.
. The `jmp compare` and `je display` instructions are totally redundant (*).
. The single character output function is not enough to display a 16-bit number.
Check ["Displaying numbers with DOS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos/45904076#45904076) to learn how to display your result.

This is my version of your program. You'll recognize much of what you've written but in a better and correct order...

```
  mov   ax, @data
  mov   ds, ax
  mov   cx, 2
  mov   si, offset arr
  lodsw
  mov   bx, ax
next:
  lodsw
  cmp   bx, ax      ;We want to divide the bigger number by the smaller one
  jb    divide
  xchg  bx, ax
  jmp   divide
repeat:
  mov   ax, bx
  mov   bx, dx
divide:
  xor   dx, dx      ;Zero DX
  div   bx
  test  dx, dx      ;Test if DX is zero
  jnz   repeat
  dec   cx
  jnz   next
  ; the GCD is in BX at this point
  ; use the above link to "Displaying numbers with DOS" to show the result.
```

At the expense of doing 1 division extra, it is possible to avoid ordering the numbers beforehand. That 1st division will establish the correct ordering for you. Moreover that 1st division is only *extra* half the time (on average).
This in turn makes it easy to simplify the jumping in the code. Less jumping around is always a good thing (*).
Furthermore I've not used `CX` since I could just as well iterate based on `SI`. Why waste a good register?

```
  mov   ax, @data
  mov   ds, ax
  mov   si, offset arr
  mov   dx, [si]
next:
  add   si, 2
  mov   bx, [si]
repeat:
  mov   ax, bx
  mov   bx, dx
  xor   dx, dx
  div   bx
  test  dx, dx
  jnz   repeat
  mov   dx, bx
  cmp   si, offset arr+4    ;End of the array minus 2
  jb    next
  ; the GCD is in BX (and also in DX) at this point
  ; use the above link to "Displaying numbers with DOS" (it's really good!) to show the result.
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It really worked.Also, displaying numbers with dos was very helpful.